# Customize the Outlook 2016 inspector ribbon in VS 2015 from similar Outlook 2010 code sample for VS 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I am looking to develop a basic com add-in for Office 2016 (perhaps globally for some of the other office apps - most likely, Excel, Word, PowerPoint, Publisher & OneNote) but in this instance for Outlook 2016 and specifically to add an 'Insert from Scanner" function to the "Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose" Inspector Ribbon in a custom group ("Scanner's & Cameras") on it's "Insert" Tab.

This is my first VSTO com add-in project and I am new to code (but a willing learner!). My extensive research has gleaned little in step-by-step advice but I have identified the following code sample from microsoft
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/VBOutlookRibbonXml-bc478854 which I had hoped to adapt (perhaps utilising the following 'scan' function vb code):

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long

Private Function TempPath() As String
    Const MaxPathLen = 256 ' Max length of the path, just as big as possible

    Dim FolderName As String ' Name of the folder
    Dim ReturnVar As Long ' Return Value

    FolderName = String(MaxPathLen, 0)
    ReturnVar = GetTempPath(MaxPathLen, FolderName)

    If ReturnVar <> 0 Then
        TempPath = Left(FolderName, InStr(FolderName, Chr(0)) - 1)
    Else
        TempPath = vbNullString
    End If
End Function

Sub Scan(control As IRibbonControl)
    Const olEditorWord = 4
    Dim objCommonDialog As WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim objImage As WIA.ImageFile
    Dim strDateiname As String
    Dim ActiveObject As Object, ActiveTarget As Object
    ' instantiate Scan WIA objects
    Set objCommonDialog = New WIA.CommonDialog
    Set objImage = objCommonDialog.ShowAcquireImage
    strDateiname = Environ$("TEMP") & "\Scan.jpg" ' set temporary file
    If Not objImage Is Nothing Then
        If Dir(strDateiname) <> "" Then Kill strDateiname
        objImage.SaveFile strDateiname 'save into temp file
        DoEvents

        'Insert the picture into the office application:
        Select Case Trim$(Replace$(Application.Name, "Microsoft", ""))
          Case "Excel"
            Set ActiveObject = CallByName(Application, "ActiveSheet", VbGet)
            Set ActiveTarget = CallByName(Application, "ActiveCell", VbGet)
            If ActiveTarget Is Nothing Then
                'Insert into a chart, etc.
                ActiveObject.Shapes.AddPicture _
                strDateiname, False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1
            Else
                'Insert into a sheet at the active cell
                ActiveObject.Shapes.AddPicture _
                strDateiname, False, True, ActiveTarget.Left, ActiveTarget.Top, -1, -1
            End If

          Case "Outlook"
            Set ActiveObject = CallByName(Application, "ActiveInspector", VbGet)
            If ActiveObject Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox "Create a new mail and try again"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            With ActiveObject
                If .IsWordMail And .EditorType = olEditorWord Then
                    .WordEditor.Application.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture strDateiname
                End If
            End With

          Case "PowerPoint"
            Set ActiveObject = CallByName(ActiveWindow, "View", VbGet)
            ActiveObject.Slide.Shapes.AddPicture strDateiname, False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1
          Case "Publisher"
            Set ActiveObject = CallByName(Application, "ActiveDocument", VbGet)
            ActiveObject.ActiveView.ActivePage.Shapes.AddPicture strDateiname, False, True, 0, 0, -1, -1
          Case "Word"
            Set ActiveObject = CallByName(Application, "Selection", VbGet)
            ActiveObject.InlineShapes.AddPicture strDateiname
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately the above Microsoft Office Development Centre Sample code is for Office 2010 and VS 2010 and so can't be accessed.

1. How can I adapt the sample for use with Office (Outlook) 2016 and VS 2015?
2. Can the above VB code block be inserted (as written) to replace the code of one the test buttons on the sample, or will it require adapting further?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the classes in the sample project into your VS 2015 project. The sample project is using a project template for a version of Office that VS 2015 doesn't support, and the Interop references would be different as well.

If you're looking to add a custom Ribbon button, just add a Ribbon (Visual Designer) item (or Ribbon (XML) item) from the Office/SharePoint node in the Add New Item dialog.